# Using add_shortcode() in WordPress to create content section in home page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I wanted to create a section with some content in the home page in wordpress, for that I had used add_shortcode() in function.php. And its working  well so far.. but I want to know if I am doing it correctly or should I do it by other better way ? My code:

```
add_shortcode('homemiddle', 'display_middle_info');

function display_middle_info() {

$url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();  

$content =" 
        <section class='gallery-section masonry-gallery padd-bott-60 bg-lightgrey'>
         <h2>My Title</h3>
         <a href='#'>GET FREE CONSULTATION</a> <a href='#'>ENTRANCE TEST 2018-19</a>

        </section>";    

  return $content;

}
```

and to output in my template file I am doing by :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[homemiddle]' );?>
```

It's doing the job but I still want to confirm that it is an appropriate methodolgy, as I am new to WordPress development. Please Guide Me... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this code is correct if you want boost up function you can use this:

```
add_shortcode('homemiddle', 'display_middle_info');
function display_middle_info($atts) {
   $url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();  

   $content = "";
   $content .= "<section class='gallery-section masonry-gallery padd-bott-60 bg-lightgrey'>";
   $content .= "<h2>My Title</h3>";
   $content .= "<a href='#'>GET FREE CONSULTATION</a> <a href='#'>ENTRANCE TEST 2018-19</a>";
   $content .= "</section>";  

   if($atts['id']){
      $content .= "<div>ID: ".$atts['id']." passed</div>";
   }
   if($atts['another'] == 1){
      $content .= "<div>This shortcode have another args passed!</div>";
   }
   if($atts['another'] == 0){
      $content .= "<div>This shortcode have another args NOT PASSED!</div>";
   }

   return $content;
}
```

so, you can use more shortcode args. e.g.:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[homemiddle]' ); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[homemiddle id=254]' ); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[homemiddle another=0]' ); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[homemiddle another=1]' ); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[homemiddle id=254 another=1]' ); ?>
```

I hope to have helped you, for each question also comments on my post

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if its working, its working! This looks fine. Typically, I use shortcodes when I want to do complex logic or work with dynamic data but be able to paste the shortcode in the wysiwyg editor or a template file or I want to empower non technical users to use within the CMS admin interface.

If you only need to output some static content once, a shortcode might be overkill but there is nothing wrong with your implementation.

Comment: Yap can u please suggest me what I should use instead of shotcodes? thank u for ur help..!

Comment: There is no right answer and every situation is different. Sometimes a widget with a text area is a great solution. Sometimes adding static content in the wysiwig editor is good, too. Your shortcode looks good and it works and its a perfectly good solution. You will just figure out which solutions work best for your websites as you make more of them. Don't get caught up in worrying about what is perfect just follow best practices coding standards and document your code and keeping learning Wordpress if you like it.